# Cloning an app from github -- missing module depencines. How to install all at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm

I am cloning clementine.js from github at this URL:

https://github.com/johnstonbl01/clementinejs-fcc.git

However, when I try to run it by cd'ing into the folder with "server.js" and typing "node server.js" I get an error saying that the 'mongoose' module hasn't been installed. Looking at the package.json file, it looks like many of the modules in clementine.js are ones I haven't installed before. Is there a way to use command line node to just install anything in the package.json file that I haven't install yet?

Thanks!

Comment: Run npm install in the app folder

Comment: Just noticed [this section of the page you linked to](https://github.com/johnstonbl01/clementinejs-fcc#installation--startup). So they did mention it. But with your question title, hopefully this will be useful to others in the future, because it's generic enough, and this applies to thousands of projects that use npm...

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was following a separate tutorial and didn't actually read the github startup page. (Didn't even think to check!) Next time I will. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you use `npm install` from the directory containing the `package.json` file. This is one of the great things about package managers: You just *list* the dependencies without having to have them actually checked into the project's repository (which is good, as there are sometimes thousands upon thousands of files involved).

Comment: LOL. I didn't realize you could run that without a module name. Thank you!